# How to find out which application is causing the computer to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

My computer went to sleep (actually, it looked more like hibernating) in the middle of an active time, without any warning.

In the Event log, the message was:

> The system is entering sleep.
>
> Sleep Reason: Application API

It doesn't give any other information. Is there a way to find out which application caused this call?

Comment: Is this totally random or do you notice any pattern?

Comment: @DaveRook It happened only once so far, but I'm curious about ways to diagnose such event, in general.

Comment: @DaveRook - I managed to reproduce it. It happens when i play on external monitor (tv). As long as the lid of the laptop is opened, no problem. When I close the lid, it will go to hibernate after around 10 minutes. Easy to circumvent for my personal case, but that doesn't tell the actual culprit.

Comment: Ancient question just bumped to the home page.  It sounds like the culprit is the power options defining the action when the lid is closed.

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately those were set to "do nothing". So probably something more hidden

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_turned_on_times.html

[image: TurnedOnTimesView screenshot]

Super useful for more than this situation, but a lifeline when trying to troubleshoot sleep / shutdown / hibernate issues.

Comment: Link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Check task manager and ensure there is nothing in there which prompts
>   this behavior. Or check the power options.
>
> You can use a clean boot to find if another program running at the
>   same time as Internet Explorer is causing this to happen. A clean boot
>   with only load Microsoft processes, and allow you to identify which
>   process is causing the problem.
>
> - Click Start
> - Type msconfig into the search field
> - Press Enter on your keyboard
> - Click Continue on the User Account Control (If prompted)
> - Click Selective startup
> - Uncheck Load startup items
> - Click the Services tab
> - Check the Hide all Microsoft services box
> - Click Disable all
> - Click OK
> - Click Restart Now
>
> Once your computer has finished restarting, test to see if you still
>   get the same problem in Internet Explorer. If not then you just have
>   to identify which service/startup item was causing the problem.
>
> - Click Start
> - Type msconfig into the search field
> - Press Enter on your keyboard
> - Click Continue on the User Account Control (If prompted)
> - Click the Services tab
> - Check the Hide all Microsoft services box
> - Check (Enable) the top half of the service boxes
> - Click OK
> - Click Restart Now
>
> Once your computer has restarted, again test to see if the problem is
>   still gone. If so, then the services you enabled are good to stay.
>   Repeat the enabling process for half of the remaining disabled
>   services and continue this process until the problem returns or all
>   services are enabled. If the problem returns then you will need to
>   test the last batch of services you enabled one by one to find which
>   was causing the problem to occur.
>
> If you enable all services and the problem still hasn’t returned:
>
> - Click Start
> - Type msconfig into the search field
> - Press Enter on your keyboard
> - Click Continue on the User Account Control (If prompted)
> - Click the Startup tab
> - Check (Enable) the top half of the service boxes
> - Click OK
> - Click Restart Now
>
> Follow the same process as before, with testing after each restart. If
>   the problem hasn’t returned, go back and enable half of the remaining
>   list of startup items and continue the process until the problem has
>   returned. Then you will need to test the last batch of startup items
>   you enabled one by one to find which causes the problem to occur.
>
> Once you have identified which service/startup item causes the problem
>   in Internet Explorer you will need to either disable/uninstall/update
>   the program to avoid further problems.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/windows-goes-into-sleep-mode-on-its-own-while/9017bdac-9fef-4f7c-9e56-47976d30b7e3)

Comment: Empirical method. It would be effective ultimately, in the event that this is a problem which is reproducing regularly, though it would consume a LOT of time. So far, it happened to me once only, so it wouldn't be really adapted. Either way, it's more of a last resort.